# Finding Date Conversion Rate Logic

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I need your help to complete this sequence, I have to find the right logic to go from one date to another and thus find what the rate corresponds to.

For now, all I could find, and which seems pretty obvious, is the number of years between the two dates, but the decimal part is not very intuitive.

- 04-09-2017 → 31-12-2022 = 5.3205
- 04-09-2018 → 31-12-2022 = 4.3205
- 29-09-2013 → 31-12-2022 = 9.2521
- 28-03-2011 → 31-12-2022 = ?

**My questions are therefore**: What is the relationship between these values ​​(5.3205,4.3205,9.2521) and the dates that precede them? What logic makes it possible to achieve these values?

***Thank you !***

Comment: But where is this coming from? Possibly calculations in Excel?

Comment: @SeanRoberson It's from a seniority report.

Comment: $117/365$ and $92/365$ might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

After some simple computation, it's just the number of years between those dates, including decimals. The decimal tells you the fraction of the year passed.

[This WolframAlpha query](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=days%20between%20September%2029%2C%202013%20and%20December%2031%2C%202022) demonstrates one of them. In short - take the total number of days and divide by 365.

Comment: I have already tried this method, do it and you'll find (5.3260) for the first sequence (1944 / 365), which is not the exact number (5.3205), different decimals !

Comment: Include leap years. In my opinion, it's such a small difference it doesn't matter. You also didn't state that you tried this method, otherwise I wouldn't have suggested it.

Comment: The leap year is already included in the count (1944)